# Do Mechadendrite melee weapon attacks benefit from the +5 WS bonus for Good craftsmanship?

Tags: equipment, dark-heresy-2e

Second-edition Dark Heresy.

From craftsmanship:

> Good: An eye towards balance and design means this weapon grants a +5
>   bonus to all Weapon Skill tests made with it.

From the cybernetics section:

> All mechadendrite cybernetics are considered to be of Good
>   craftsmanship unless otherwise noted.

Does the bonus to melee weapons of Good craftmanship apply to Mechandrites that have an included melee weapon (or weapon functionality)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No

Core Rulebook page 142
Good:
An  eye  towards  balance  and  design  means  this  weapon
grants a +5 bonus to all Weapon Skill tests made with it.

Mechadendrites are not weapon themselves. **They are cybernetics.**

Comment: But good-quality armour doesn't have anythng like that bonus, it just raises the maximum agility while wearing it by five.

Comment: @Zso Sorry, I forgot that this was one of cool things kicked out from 1st ed :/